# if first user already login, how to prevent second user login on another tab

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6, angular-route-guards

I am trying to prevent multiple simultaneous logins where if first user already login, it will prevent second user from login on another tab, i need advice on what should I need to do, based on google, i can use localstorage and authguard, and had  implemented both but not solve the problem,

**authentication.service.ts**

```
isUserAuthenticated(): boolean {
    const user = localStorage.getItem(appConstant.currentUser);
    return user != null;
}
```

**login.component.ts**

```
ngOnInit(): void {
if (this.authenService.isUserAuthenticated()) {
  this.router.navigate([UrlConstants.UserSetting])
 }
}
```

when first user already login, open the second tab by paste login Url, it work, login will redirect to user setting, but when login page have been ready for both tab, when the first user login, the second user also can login using different account.

Comment: with localStorage this should be done. What did you tried till now post it here with question..

Comment: @ganesh045 i have updated my question

Comment: where you are setting the currentUser to `localStorage`. I think you need to check there too...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when you are setting the data to `localStorage` we need to check is there any user already in logged in.

```
isUserAuthenticated(): boolean {
  if(localStorage.getItem(currentUser) != null)    
       return true;
  else {
     localStorage.setItem('currentUser',user);
       return false;
    }
  }
```

i think this will solve your issue :)

Comment: Im try to check if there any user already logged in as you stated above, but it didnt solve the problem @ganesh045

Comment: where your calling this `isUserAuthenticated()`  method. try to call this method after immediately once user authenticated.

Comment: try implemented it as you stated above and solved it, thanks ! @ganesh045

Answer (score 0):

For your requirement, you should have a variable stored in localStorage like:

```
totalUsers: number =0;
localStorage.setItem('totalUsersCount', totalUsers);
```

Increment totalUsers everytime a successful login happens. Decrement / clear it when log out happens.
So, on login, check if the localstorage value is equal to zero. If so, allow login. Else, throw an error.

Answer (score -1):

If is already login you can redirect direct dashboard page so write down this snip in login component:

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
    if (this.accountService.isAuthenticated()) {
      this.router.navigate(['/dashboard']);
     }
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for your answer. Please provide more details about your solution. Code snippets, high quality descriptions, or any relevant information would be great. Clear and concise answers are more helpful and easier to understand for everyone. [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77045362/edit) your answer with specifics to raise the quality of your answer. For more information: [How To: Write good answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Happy coding!